# Detecting winner and setting up game loop

Tags: c#

I am making a game and everything is completely done except that the game does not detect the end of the game.

I tried setting up a method for endgame and the program doesn't give me errors. It compiles. It just does not detect it when the score of a player hits 6. in that case, I want the program to set endGame to true and break out of the loop and display the winner. Instead, It keeps printing "The current player wins" each turn. I dont know what the logical problem is. BTW movement is what moves my players on the board.

```
 static void Movement(int i, int rolled, char direction) // movement
 {
    Console.WriteLine("");
    Console.WriteLine("Making a move for Player " + players[i].Name);

    if (direction == 'u' || direction == 'U')
    {
        if (players[i].X - rolled < 0)
            players[i].X = players[i].X + 8 - rolled;
        else
            players[i].X = players[i].X - rolled;
    }
    else if (direction == 'd' || direction == 'D')
    {
        if (players[i].X + rolled > 7)
            players[i].X = players[i].X - 8 + rolled;
        else
            players[i].X = players[i].X + rolled;
    }
    else if (direction == 'l' || direction == 'L')
    {
        if (players[i].Y - rolled < 0)
            players[i].Y = players[i].Y + 8 - rolled;
        else
            players[i].Y = players[i].Y - rolled;
    }
    else if (direction == 'r' || direction == 'R')
    {
        if (players[i].Y + rolled > 7)
            players[i].Y = players[i].Y - 8 + rolled;
        else
            players[i].Y = players[i].Y + rolled;
    }

}
static void Main()
    {
 var gameOver = false; //endgame loop does not work

        while (true)
        {
            for (int round = 0; round < 20 && !gameOver; round++)
            {

                for (int playerturn = 1; playerturn < totalplayers && !gameOver; playerturn++) //Sets up turns for each player

                    for (int i = 0; i < totalplayers && !gameOver; i++)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine(players[i].Name + " 's turn. Roll it! ");
                        Console.WriteLine();
                        int rolled;

                        if (dicechoice == 1) //do the the random method otherwise choose number
                        {

                            rolled = DiceRead();
                        }


                        else
                        {

                            Console.ReadLine();
                            rolled = DiceThrow();
                        }

                        Console.WriteLine("");
                        Console.WriteLine(players[i].Name + " rolled " + rolled);
                        Console.WriteLine("");

                        Console.WriteLine(" Please pick a direction: (U,D,L,R)");
                        Console.WriteLine("");
                        char direction;

                        do
                        {
                            direction = Console.ReadKey().KeyChar; //store direction as char
                            if (direction != 'U' && direction != 'D' && direction != 'L' && direction != 'R' && direction != 'u' && direction != 'd' && direction != 'l' && direction != 'r')
                            {
                                Console.WriteLine("Invalid input.. (U,D,L,R)");
                                Console.WriteLine();
                            }

                        } while (direction != 'U' && direction != 'D' && direction != 'L' && direction != 'R' && direction != 'u' && direction != 'd' && direction != 'l' && direction != 'r');
                        Console.WriteLine("");




                        Movement(i, rolled, direction);

                        Console.WriteLine("");


                        if (players[i].Stash == 6)
                        {

                            Console.WriteLine(players[i].Name + " wins.");
                            gameOver = true;
                            break;
                        }
      }

            }

            Console.WriteLine("Would you like to play again?");
            gameOver = false;
            if (Console.ReadKey().Key != ConsoleKey.Y)
                break;
        }


    }
```

Comment: Post more code. What are we supposed to make of this? What about the `Movement` method?

Comment: ` Movement(i, rolled, direction); gameOver = false;   { ` what is this right curly bracket for?

Comment: The code you posted here is very badly formatted which makes it harder to read.  Also your use of curly brackets is very inconsistent.  You have else statements that don't use them (which is ok for single statement else blocks, but would be more readable if you included the brackets anyway), at least one for loop that also does not use them, at least one bracket that seems to have no reason to be there.  Your indenting is all wack.  Lots of pointless blank lines.  If you want other people to help you, for free, the least you could do is provide readable code.

Comment: You are looping based on a boolean flag, and the flag is never changed inside the loop, so it will loop forever. I can't really understand your code because you're missing pieces of it, but I'm guessing you need to move the location of your do/while loop so it wraps an entire turn (including the if for gameover check)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like the problem is here:

```
 if (players[i].Stash == 6)
     gameOver=true;
 do
 {
     Console.WriteLine(players[i].Name + " wins.");
 }
 while (gameOver == true);
```

I'm not sure what purpose the loop after  you set gameOver to true is. Just print the winner's name when `Stash == 6`.

To make the game ask to be restarted, move `gameOver` to the scope of the main method, surround it with a while loop to allow the game to be restarted, and add `!gameover` to the for loop to make it exit on game over.

```
 var gameover = false;
 while (true)
 {
    for (int round = 0; round < 20 && !gameover; round++)
    {
```

Then with the player reaches 6 points (Note that your code doesn't increment the points anywhere), set `gameover` to true and break out of the loop.

```
if (players[i].Stash == 6)
{

    Console.WriteLine(players[i].Name + " wins.");
    gameover = true;
    break;
}
```

At the bottom of your code, complete the while loop, and exit it if the user doesn't press Y.

```
   Console.WriteLine("Would you like to play again?");
   gameover = false;
   if (Console.ReadKey().Key != ConsoleKey.Y)
   break;
}
```

Note you will need to reset the scores as well.

Comment: I want to break out of the gameloop and ask the players if they would like to play again after printing players[i].Name + "wins."

Comment: See my edit, add those three parts and it should work.

Comment: The solution you gave is written in a way I could understand. I did the three steps. It compiles but still does not display the winner or break from the loop when the stash hits 6. I feel like the issue is minor somewhere in the code. Thank you

Comment: Could you post your updated code? I tested this and it works (Although I don't have the source to the dice methods so I just increased the score by 3).

Comment: I posted the updated code. I have a way of inputting the dice myself so I can test it. I just score 6 by a player in the game and see what happens and it doesnt really seem to work

Comment: Check the for loop, I meant to add the second check, it should be `for (int round = 0; round < 20 && !gameover; round++)` not `for (int round = 0; !gameover; round++)`

Comment: @denzi Add the `!gameOver` check to all 3 of your for loops, not just the first one. For example, `for (int i = 0; i < totalplayers && !gameOver; i++)`

Comment: Fixed that error too. Still not doing anything when stash hits 6

Comment: It works for me without them on all three but that can be done just in case.

Comment: I posted my updated code. It still doesnt work for some reason. This is driving me mad

Comment: Where are you adding to the stash? If I add 1 to the stash after the dice code, it works when it reaches 6.

Comment: Are you sure that the stash is being incremented to 6? Use a breakpoint and try and debug it.

Answer (score 0):

You appear to be missing part of your code, but your loop is caused by this section of code

```
if (players[i].Stash == 6)
     gameOver=true;

 do
 {
     Console.WriteLine(players[i].Name + " wins.");
 }
 while (gameOver == true);
```

It is saying

> Check if gameOver is equal to true, and if so then Console.WriteLine until gameOver flag is not true

It will continuously loop because there is nothing within your do/while loop to change the value of the gameOver flag.

It sounds like what you actually want is some logic like this :

```
gameOver = false;

do
{
    // whatever steps to each round are goes here

    // check to see if someone has won, and if yes set flag to break loop
    if (players[i].Stash == 6)
        gameOver=true;         

}
while (gameOver == false);

// this will not execute until the do/while loop above completes
Console.WriteLine(players[i].Name + " wins.");
```

This will say

> As long as the gameOver flag is false, do whatever steps to each round are and check if there is a winner. Once there's a winner, set the gameOver flag to true, which will break the loop and print out the winner